# Fetching WFS layer grid of 1*1 mtr from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, vector-grid

I have created 1*1 grid in QGIS from Vector->Research tools->Create grid. And I have converted that grid file to shape and hosted in the GeoServer. When I am trying to fetch that layer after applying CQLFilter I am getting larger grid, though I am getting correct no of features when I am requesting WFS request  My question is there any setting in GeoServer which will return me a smaller grid size.

[image: Screenshot result of 1*1 grid]

Though I am getting this no of response

[image: Response from WFS]

My query which I am running is

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=cemtics:grid&outputFormat=json&srsname=EPSG:4326&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom,POLYGON((77.230264 28.664398,77.230836 28.664544,77.230951 28.664271,77.230362 28.664115,77.230264 28.664398)))

SHP INFO

[image: SHP FILE INFO]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the details for your shapefile (e.g. from ogrinfo) and the exact query you are using to GeoServer WFS? Also, can you show the relevant part of the GetCapabilities response?

Comment: @BradHards I have modified my question. And wrote query which I am performing. Looking a way to find ogrinfo of the shapefile

Comment: Install gdal if you don't already have it, run ogrinfo. Also, how did you publish your shapefile in GeoServer (actual / forced CRS?)

Comment: I have used forces CRS

Comment: What are the values? Are you forcing it to EPSG:4326? If so, that is likely the  problem.